# Angular stepper when is completed or finished it is an error, this is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am facing with a problem is not a function, in other page it works perfect but I made angular stepper in the dialog and then it is not working.

Here is the code of dialog.

```
<mat-step>
  <ng-template matStepLabel>Page 3</ng-template>
  <div class="form-block">
    <div class="form-group" *ngIf="selectedTemplate === 1">
    <div>
      <label>Select:</label>
    </div>
    <app-dropdown [items]="productDropdownOptions" placeholder="Select Product" [(ngModel)]="selectedItemId"></app-dropdown>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" *ngIf="selectedTemplate === 2">
      <div>
        <label>Select:</label>
      </div>
      <app-dropdown [items]="valueItemClass" [(ngModel)]="selectedItemId"></app-dropdown>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
  <button mat-button (click)="complete()">Finish</button>
```

This is the TS

```
 @Input() onStepperCompleted;
 @ViewChild('stepper') stepper;
 onFinish = () => {
    this.onStepperCompleted(this.selectedTemplate, this.selectedItemId);
  }
```

It is showing me an error like this.

```
TypeError: _this.onStepperCompleted is not a function
```

Comment: Have you looked at the official examples? https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview

Comment: I have looked but there is just @Input: complete: boolean, it doesn't make any sense i think it doesn't show any exmaple what makes or something, do you have any suggestion ?

Comment: @ZhuniqiA did you solve this issue. I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: Sorry I have fixed this, show me your code and i will tell how to fix ?